# how to track the screen in landscape or portrait view in android?

Tags: android

I worked in a tabactivity, I set the gravity for tabs as bottom. If I change the screen from portrait to landscape, I can't see the tabs.
How can I do it? I need an example please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you do not have a separate XML file dedicated to landscape format, you might need to create one and specify the landscape-layout look.

Create another `main.xml` file with the specifics of how your program should look in landscape mode. The file shoud reside inside your `res/layout-land/` folder.

When that is all said and done, in potrait orientation, Android will use `main.xml` found in `res/layout` and in landscape `main.xml` found in `res/layout-land`.

Comment: how to restrict the landscape orientation??

Comment: what do you mean by restrict the landscape orientation? Disable it?

Comment: @AnthonyForloney I think Praveen means how to force an activity into and keep it in landscape orientation. One way is to call the following in the onCreate of one's activity:
  setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);